# Using a off-the-shelf pressure gauge to measure water pressure

Tags: water-pressure, gauge

I want to measure water pressure around my house, I can't find any pressure gauges made for that, so I will make do.

I've found some that are for Acetylene in the right range, but they have "use no oil" written on it. Now, I don't know if that is telling me to not use oil (glicerin) in the gauge, or if that is telling me that the pressure gauge can't be used with liquids, or something else.

Any thoughts?

Comment: googling for "water pressure gauge" works for me. £7-£15 UK. Like you, I would be wary of using a gas gauge for water.

Comment: Technically I don't think there is a difference in a gauge for gas or water, both are fluid and pressure gauges works by means of a bourdon tube that don't cares which fluid is inside of it. The only caveat would be something that corrodes or reacts with the bourdon tube, but then this is another problem.

Comment: Most hardware, and home improvement stores sell a [pressure gauge that fits on a hose bib](http://www.homedepot.com/p/3-in-P2A-Water-Pressure-Gauge-P2A/100575619). These can be used [with adapters](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/74354/33), to fit different types of outlets.  With most of these gauges, you can remove the hose bib adapter, and you'll be left with a 1/4" NPT connection. From there, you can add whatever adapter you need.

Comment: You should be able to find an [aerator to garden hose adapter](http://www.homedepot.com/p/NEOPERL-55-64-in-x-3-4-in-Solid-Brass-Female-x-Male-Hose-Adapter-37-0112-98/202243063). For reference, standard US aerator threads are 15/16" - 27 TPI Male, and 55/64" - 27 TPI Female.  Garden hose is 3/4" GHT.

Comment: Not in US. Here there is little variety in hardware in general. Also, there are very few large stores like HomeDepot, Lowes, and the like.

Answer (score 2):

The "Use No Oil" is a warning placed on the gauge that may have application in a pressurized gas setup. The most common example being on an oxygen / acetylene gas welding rig. Any of the fittings including the manifold, meters, pressure regulators and connection hoses in such application are always used with clean non-oiled threaded fittings. The reason is that high pressure compressed gas (oxygen) can explode in the presence of oil and any possible spark that may occur when assembling the components of the welding outfit onto the compressed gas bottles.

Comment: So I'm probably fine using that for water, right?

Comment: I would not jump to that conclusion. Meters use various types of internal construction and some may be designed for general gas or liquid application whilst others may be specific to one medium or the other.